# Wifi connection on a specific network is slow and shows strange messages

Tags: networking, wireless, kde, plasma-5

I'm on Kubuntu with Plasma 5.
Everything network related is working correcly, except with my own home WIFI. The ESSID is configured to autoconnect, but when I logon in my laptop, the connection manager hangs for a while trying to connect, and after 5 seconds it shows the message

" deactivated and No secrets were provided"

(sorry if the translation isn't exact, my system is not English located).

Anyway, after this message, the connection goes up and I am correctly connected...

here it is /var/log/syslog upon boot. Note that the problem occurs only after login, while if I deactivate and reactivate wifi when the connection is up and working, everything works as expected.
The SSID is Mauro-Pupinia-5GHz

https://pastebin.com/bCUrekwi

Comment: Is there anything about this in `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: @GreatUncleBulgaria see my edit

Comment: Right after you login, open a terminal and type `service network-manager restart` does this fix it temporarily?

Comment: Maybe its slow because you are connecting to a TOR node ??

Comment: No, I'm not.
And moreover, AGAIN, it's the only connection that has this problem!

Comment: Can you try removing the connection from the networking and re-pairing the connection. I.e., delete it and reconnect to accesss point so it will prompt you for password again. It seems to have problem with the pass key, whether reading it, using it or retrieving it from key chain probably.

Comment: Seems like it might be a problem with incorrect protocol implementation like this [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=767515) for which [this](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2018-January/msg00019.html) page gives using `nmcli connection modify <conn> ipv4.dhcp-client-id 01:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` (where 01:xx:.. is your MAC). Alternatively, you might have your MAC address set to random, sometimes that causes problems.

Comment: @pbhj no luck...